# Angular 2 add css class to selected item

Tags: angular

How can I in Angular 2 add active class to selected item on click and remove that class on again click. But for multiple items in list.

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemSelected(item)">
  <p>{{ item }}</p>
</li>
```

For example I have list of 5 items. Click on first item add class active and then for fifth item add also class active.

Comment: Take a look at [NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass). Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

[NgStyle] https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

[NgClass] https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

For example:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemSelected(item)">
  <p [NgClass]="listSelectedItems.indexOf(item)>-1"?"your-active-class":"your-inactive-class" >{{ item }}</p>
</li>
```

With *itemSelected()* which add or remove item from *listSelectedItems*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the syntax from [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-targets):

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="selectItem(item)" [class.selected]="isSelected(item)">
    <p>{{ item }}</p>
</li>
```

This seems a bit more idiomatic than using `ng-class`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this answer with the corresponding code in the `ts` file?